# Cocoapods can't find .a file

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, .a

I got error with use cocoapods in XCode.
[image]

Why do I run .xcworkspace without generating this .a file in DerivedData? 
[image]
[image]
This is someone else's DerivedData.
Why do I only have xxx.app?

Comment: That linker command line looks broken to me.  For example `-lc++` and `-lstdc++`?  There be dragons.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove CocoaPods from project and then re-install it**

- Delete the standalone files (Podfile Podfile.lock and your Pods directory)
- Delete the generated xcworkspace
- Open your xcodeproj file, delete the references to Pods.xcconfig and libPods.a (in the Frameworks group)
  Under your Build Phases delete the Copy Pods Resources and Check Pods Manifest.lock phases.
  After those steps you should be set with a single xcodeproj that existed before you integrated CocoaPods.